# How can I parse a JSON string in which objects are not comma separated?

Tags: javascript, json

I have been trying to parse this JSON that I am getting from an API. It just doesn't seem to work. It inserts the whole response into a single object or array when I try to pass it into an object or array. I'm just posting the API response and not my code that I tried:

```
{"canonical_url": "http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/"}{"shop_properties": {"is_hypernode": false, "hypernode_without_magento": false, "loadtime_milliseconds": 638}}{"admin_url": null}{"security.supee5344": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "backend url required", "riskRating": "low", "result": "unkn", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.supee5994": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "installed", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.ransomware": {"magento2": true, "resultString": "safe", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.cart2quoterce": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "safe", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.ajaxcartrce": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "safe", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.opendev": {"magento2": true, "resultString": "safe", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.openversioncontrol": {"magento2": true, "resultString": "safe", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.sslcheck": {"magento2": true, "resultString": "misconfigured", "riskRating": "medium", "result": "fail", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.guruincinfection": {"magento2": true, "resultString": "safe", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.creditcardhijack": {"magento2": true, "resultString": "safe", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.visbot": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "safe", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.cryptojacking": {"magento2": true, "resultString": "safe", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.outdatedserverversion": {"magento2": true, "resultString": "unknown", "riskRating": "low", "result": "unkn", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.amastyopendownload": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "safe", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.cacheleak": {"magento2": true, "resultString": "safe", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.openmagmi": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "safe", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.webforms": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "safe", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.bruteforce": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "protected", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.magversion": {"magento2": true, "resultString": "CE 2.1.0 - 2.1.2", "riskRating": "high", "result": "fail", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.supee6788": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "installed", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.supee8788": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "unknown", "riskRating": "low", "result": "unkn", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.supee9652": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "safe", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.supee10570": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "patched", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.supee10752": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "patched", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.supee6285": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "unknown", "riskRating": "low", "result": "unkn", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.supee6482": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "unknown", "riskRating": "low", "result": "unkn", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.exposedapi": {"magento2": true, "resultString": "safe", "riskRating": "low", "result": "ok", "magento1": false, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.supee10266": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "backend url required", "riskRating": "low", "result": "unkn", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.supee9767": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "unknown", "riskRating": "low", "result": "unkn", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.supee10415": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "unknown", "riskRating": "low", "result": "unkn", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}{"security.supee7405": {"magento2": false, "resultString": "unknown", "riskRating": "low", "result": "unkn", "magento1": true, "cloudflareCacheHit": null}}
```

Comment: It isn't JSON. Fix the API so it is JSON. (Or write a custom parser to attempt to separate out the different objects … which is an awful idea).

Comment: I do not have the access to the API. This is an external API.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: @Quentin http://www.relaxedjson.org/

Comment: you should request the developer of the api your using to check this this is an invalid json response.

Comment: Please shorten the *broken* JSON snippet to the relevant amount of information, it is just a lot of garbage otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/really-relaxed-json
can help you out here. Unfortunately for some reason StackOverflow snippets cannot run it when included as an external resource (from CDN https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/relaxed-json@1.0.1/relaxed-json.js), so I created a Stackblitz demo here:

> https://js-ei2iz2.stackblitz.io <-- check the console

Here's the editable example:

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ei2iz2

```js
let response = `{  
       "canonical_url":"http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/"
    }{  
       "shop_properties":{  
          "is_hypernode":false,
          "hypernode_without_magento":false,
          "loadtime_milliseconds":535
       }
    }{  
       "admin_url":null
    }{  
       "security.supee5344":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"backend url required",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"unkn",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.supee5994":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"installed",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.cart2quoterce":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"safe",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.ransomware":{  
          "magento2":true,
          "resultString":"safe",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.ajaxcartrce":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"safe",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.openversioncontrol":{  
          "magento2":true,
          "resultString":"safe",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.opendev":{  
          "magento2":true,
          "resultString":"safe",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.guruincinfection":{  
          "magento2":true,
          "resultString":"safe",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.creditcardhijack":{  
          "magento2":true,
          "resultString":"safe",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.visbot":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"safe",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.cryptojacking":{  
          "magento2":true,
          "resultString":"safe",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.outdatedserverversion":{  
          "magento2":true,
          "resultString":"unknown",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"unkn",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.cacheleak":{  
          "magento2":true,
          "resultString":"safe",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.amastyopendownload":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"safe",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.sslcheck":{  
          "magento2":true,
          "resultString":"misconfigured",
          "riskRating":"medium",
          "result":"fail",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.webforms":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"safe",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.openmagmi":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"safe",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.magversion":{  
          "magento2":true,
          "resultString":"CE 2.1.0 - 2.1.2",
          "riskRating":"high",
          "result":"fail",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.supee6788":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"installed",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.supee8788":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"unknown",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"unkn",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.supee9652":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"safe",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.supee10570":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"patched",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.supee10752":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"patched",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.supee6285":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"unknown",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"unkn",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.supee6482":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"unknown",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"unkn",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.exposedapi":{  
          "magento2":true,
          "resultString":"safe",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":false,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.bruteforce":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"protected",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"ok",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.supee10266":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"backend url required",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"unkn",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.supee9767":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"unknown",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"unkn",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.supee10415":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"unknown",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"unkn",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":null
       }
    }{  
       "security.supee7405":{  
          "magento2":false,
          "resultString":"unknown",
          "riskRating":"low",
          "result":"unkn",
          "magento1":true,
          "cloudflareCacheHit":nulla
       }
    }`

    response = "["+response+"]"

    console.log(RJSON.parse(response))
```

Comment: Nice answer! I would use this library in the future!

Comment: I tried this approach but still cannot traverse the response.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-uwv4ar

Comment: @MahirRawal You are actually correct. Somehow on Stackblitz the result of `toJS(fresponse)` is still considered a string - but if you copy and paste the console.log output to a Chrome console and prepend `let a = ` you'll see it is a proper Javascript Array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function parse(str) {
{
  let splitted = str.split('}{')

  let json = [];

  splitted.forEach((s, i) => {
    let fullObjectString = i == 0 ? s + '}' : i == splitted.length - 1 ? '{' + s : '{' + s + '}'
    json.push(
      JSON.parse(fullObjectString)
    )
  })

 return json
}
```

[Demo](https://beta.observablehq.com/@giorgi-ghviniashvili/stackoverflow-answers)

Comment: This could work if you can guarantee that `}{` does not occur within a string inside any of the objects.

Comment: Yes, but as I see in the example response, there is not reason why there should be `}{` in an object.

Comment: That's for the questioner to decide. I'm just pointing out that this solution is not 100% bulletproof. `}{` could be part of a unit test. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I converted your json to array of objects this way, this would parse in array of objects

```
var x=`{  
   "canonical_url":"http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/"
}{  
   "shop_properties":{  
      "is_hypernode":false,
      "hypernode_without_magento":false,
      "loadtime_milliseconds":535
   }
}{  
   "admin_url":null
}{  
   "security.supee5344":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"backend url required",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"unkn",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.supee5994":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"installed",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.cart2quoterce":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"safe",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.ransomware":{  
      "magento2":true,
      "resultString":"safe",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.ajaxcartrce":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"safe",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.openversioncontrol":{  
      "magento2":true,
      "resultString":"safe",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.opendev":{  
      "magento2":true,
      "resultString":"safe",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.guruincinfection":{  
      "magento2":true,
      "resultString":"safe",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.creditcardhijack":{  
      "magento2":true,
      "resultString":"safe",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.visbot":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"safe",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.cryptojacking":{  
      "magento2":true,
      "resultString":"safe",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.outdatedserverversion":{  
      "magento2":true,
      "resultString":"unknown",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"unkn",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.cacheleak":{  
      "magento2":true,
      "resultString":"safe",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.amastyopendownload":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"safe",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.sslcheck":{  
      "magento2":true,
      "resultString":"misconfigured",
      "riskRating":"medium",
      "result":"fail",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.webforms":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"safe",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.openmagmi":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"safe",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.magversion":{  
      "magento2":true,
      "resultString":"CE 2.1.0 - 2.1.2",
      "riskRating":"high",
      "result":"fail",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.supee6788":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"installed",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.supee8788":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"unknown",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"unkn",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.supee9652":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"safe",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.supee10570":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"patched",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.supee10752":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"patched",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.supee6285":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"unknown",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"unkn",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.supee6482":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"unknown",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"unkn",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.exposedapi":{  
      "magento2":true,
      "resultString":"safe",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":false,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.bruteforce":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"protected",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"ok",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.supee10266":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"backend url required",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"unkn",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.supee9767":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"unknown",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"unkn",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.supee10415":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"unknown",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"unkn",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}{  
   "security.supee7405":{  
      "magento2":false,
      "resultString":"unknown",
      "riskRating":"low",
      "result":"unkn",
      "magento1":true,
      "cloudflareCacheHit":null
   }
}`;
anotherString = x.replace(/}{/g, '}\,{');
anotherString = '{ "arrayOfObjects":['+anotherString+  ']}';
console.log(anotherString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you *know* this is badly formatted JSON anyway, it is probably well acceptable to do string operations.

E.g., replace "\n}{\n" with "\n},{\n" (try to use the longest possible pattern to a reduce the risk of false positives, such as }{ in some string - there shouldn't be a non-encoded newline in JSON strings.)

Comment: There are no new line characters in the response. Its just one continuous piece of data.

Comment: Choose whatever is fit to work around the bad data. Use }{"security then, for example. You know the data. If you can't get the API fixed, you need to do a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python, you can try this half json fixer

```py
    from half_json.core import JSONFixer

    s = '''{}{}{}'''  # your half json
    f = JSONFixer(100)
    result = f.fix('['+ s.strip() + ']')
    # result.success == True
    datas = json.loads(result.line)
    # [{},{},{}]
```